# Using jQuery to append different HTML into specific cells of a table

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a table where the prompts are in the first column and a page reference is in the 2nd column.  Based on the number of "hits" in an XML file, I wish to append a new column.  Each cell has a different type of input, with an id based on the loop through the XML file.

[image]

I plan to have each input read in as a snippet of HTML, change the id of each, then load that altered snippet into the needed cell.  In the example I have shown, there were 2 hits in the XML file.

How do I load a *specific* cell with *specific* code?  I have seen "first" and "last", but they all load thing generically.

Comment: What have you actually tried to do?

Comment: Posting an image is optional, posting code pertaining to issue is **required**. Provide a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

use the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method which allows you to target a specific element in the list:

```
ThirdRowFourthCol = $("tr").eq(2).find("td").eq(3);
```

Comment: I'm still missing something.  If my table has an id="myTable" and I want to load "<i>this is a test</i>", what would I need with your suggestion?